# Как работает объявление let в for

Tags: javascript

Все знают что объявление:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    alert("message")
}
```

создает на каждой итерации  отдельную переменную `i` что позволяет писать такие конструкции как:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){alert(i)},1000*i)
}
```

с применением var этого было бы невозможно без создания замыкания.

Вопрос в том как работает let? Как представить его работу в коде? Если с var понятно, то с let возникают трудности.

Comment: что именно непонято с let?

Comment: Открываем стандарт и читаем "13.3 Declarations and the Variable Statement". Грубо говоря, каждый раз в контексте создается новая ссылка и если у `var` они указывают на одну область в памяти, то у `let` ссылки контекста ссылаются на разную область.

Comment: @Grundy механизм, как так получается что в цикле для каждой итерации создается своя переменная?

Comment: @AlexKrass Читал стандарт. Там есть 3 варианта для первого "аргумента" в цикле for: `Expression(opt)` или `var VariableDeclarationList` или `LexicalDeclarationExpression(opt)`. Честно говоря сложно понять что имеется ввиду под каждым случаем. И да это 13.7.4

Comment: Собственно смотри на Runtime Semantic, там расписано что происходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схематично процесс выполнения для цикла

```
for (let i=0; i<2; i++) { 
    setTimeout(function(){alert(i)},1000*i) 
}
```

можно представить так:

```
var loopEnv = {
    i: 0
};

var iter1Env = {};
iter1Env.i = loopEnv.i; // 0

if(iter1Env.i<2 == false) return;

setTimeout(function(){alert(iter1Env.i)},1000*iter1Env.i)

var iter2Env = {};
iter2Env.i = iter1Env.i; // 0
iter2Env.i++; // 1

if(iter2Env.i<2 == false) return;

setTimeout(function(){alert(iter2Env.i)},1000*iter2Env.i)

var iter3Env = {};
iter3Env.i = iter2Env.i; // 1
iter3Env.i++; // 2

if(iter3Env.i<2 == false) return; // 2 < 2 == false -> return
```

Отсюда видно, что замыкаются на каждой итерации разные объекты. В случае с `var` это был бы один объект.

Подробнее можно увидеть в спецификации:

1. IterationStatement:

   ```
   for(LexicalDeclaration Expression; Expression) Statement
   ```
2. [Runtime Semantics: ForBodyEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-forbodyevaluation)
3. [Runtime Semantics: CreatePerIterationEnvironment( perIterationBindings )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-createperiterationenvironment)

Comment: Хоть я это и давно спрашивал, сейчас для меня не так тяжело читать доки ;)
Одна строчка удивила: `If isConst is false, let perIterationLets be boundNames; otherwise let perIterationLets be « »`. Что значит: `be « »` - что это за пробел в кавычках? Я бы понял бы null или undefined а там просто пробел.
P.S Прочитали мое объяснение про окружения?

Comment: @MaximPro, `be « »` - значит - пустой список.

Comment: принято, понято!

Answer (score 1):

**При использовании let в цикле, для каждой итерации создаётся своя переменная.**

Переменная `var –` одна на все итерации цикла и видна даже после цикла:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) { /* … */ }

alert(i); // 10
```

С переменной `let –` всё по-другому.

Каждому повторению цикла соответствует своя независимая переменная `let`. Если внутри цикла есть вложенные объявления функций, то в замыкании каждой будет та переменная, которая была при соответствующей итерации.

Пример

```
function makeArmy() {

  let shooters = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    shooters.push(function() {
      alert( i ); // выводит свой номер
    });
  }

  return shooters;
}

var army = makeArmy();

army[0](); // 0
army[5](); // 5
```

Если бы объявление было `var i`, то была бы одна переменная i на всю функцию, и вызовы в последних строках выводили бы 10

А выше объявление let i создаёт для каждого повторения блока в цикле свою переменную, которую функция и получает из замыкания в последних строках.