# [[Scope]] функции переданный в качестве аргумента

Tags: javascript, scope, область-видимости

**1**

```js
var a = 123;

function func() {
  var a = 22;
  return function test(f) {
    var a = 65;
    f();
  };
}

var b = func();

b(function() {
  console.log(a);
});
```

**2**

```js
var a = 123;

function func() {
  var a = 22;
  function test(f) {
    var a = 65;
    f();
  }
  test(function() {
    console.log(a);
  });
}

func();
```

В этих примерах видно, что `функция` переданная в качестве `аргумента` объявляется во время вызова `функции` `test`, и ее `[[Scope]]` будет равен месту вызова. В первом примере `[[Scope]]` равен `window`, а во втором `func`. В этом можно убедиться, обратив внимание на значение переменной `a`, которое возвращает `функция` переданная в качестве `аргумента`, или же внутри `функции` `test` прописать `console.dir(f)` и посмотреть какое будет значение свойства `[[Scope]]` у `функции`. Почему `функция` переданная в качестве `аргумента` не определяется внутри `функции` `test`, и тем самым не присваивает свойству `[[Scope]]` значение в виде лексического окружения, которым является функция `test`? Когда происходит выполнение `функции` `test`, то в переменную `f` присваивается уже ссылка на `функции`, а не сама `функция`, так как объявление произошло уже во время вызова `функции` `test`.

Comment: http://javascript.ru/node/680#scope

Comment: "В этих примерах видно, что функция переданная в качестве аргумента объявляется во время вызова функции test..." - первая ошибка, функции (Function Declaration) создаются до начала исполнения кода.

Comment: @Hipster, вот только тут не Function Declaration, а Function Expression.

Comment: _Почему функция переданная в качестве аргумента не определяется внутри функции test_ - потому что вычисление аргументов происходит **ДО** вызова функции

Comment: @Grundy но как тогда функция, которую передали в качестве аргумента стала Function Expression, если она во время вызова анонимная, а потом уже присваивается внутри функции test переменной f. Возможно создается временная переменная для анонимной функции, а потом она уже передалась в качестве аргумента. Я просто не знаю механизма и могу только предполагать.

Comment: _но как тогда функция, которую передали в качестве аргумента стала Function Expression_ - она им всегда и была. Я не совсем понимаю суть вопроса. ты хочешь узнать почему аргументы функции вычисляются до вызова функции?

Comment: @Grundy _Если функция создана как часть выражения, то это Function Expression._ Передача функции в качестве аргумента является выражением? И хотел узнать, в какую переменную присваивается функция, ибо в функцию test передается ссылка, а не сама функция, ибо она объявилась во время передачи.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, ни в какую. Просто при вызове функции значение этого выражения связывается с именем формального параметра `f`

Comment: @Grundy в параметр `f` передается ссылка на функцию, а не сама функция, но тогда где изначально храниться функция?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71350/discussion-between---and-grundy).

Comment: [let/for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768346/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, ты промахнулся, если ты отвечал на мой вопрос заданный в чате) Спасибо за ответ, чуть позже прочту)

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, нет не промахнулся. Я в чатах сейчас не могу писать :)

Comment: @Grundy, чего?)

Answer (score -1):

Когда во втором примере Вы вызываете функцию test c функцией-аргументом, Вы там уже жестко прописали что вывести в консоль, т.е. по сути написано следующее:

```
function func() {
  var a = 22;
  function test(f) {
    var a = 65;
    f();
  }
  test(function() {
    console.log(22);
  });
}
```

(даже при минификации кода это видно, можете проверить тут: https://javascript-minifier.com)

если Вы хотите 65, то нужно так:

```
 function func() {
      var a = 22;
      function test(f) {
        var a = 65;
        f(a);
      }
      test(function(a) {
        console.log(a);
      });
    }
```

Что касается этого момента:

> Когда происходит выполнение функции test, то в переменную f
>   присваивается уже ссылка на функции, а не сама функция

Функция это объект, а объекты в JS передаются по ссылке, а не по значению, и поэтому Scope у нее определен там, где она написана.

И может Вам будет интересно еще узнать (если не знаете) - При создании функции с использованием new Function, её свойство [[Scope]] ссылается не на текущий LexicalEnvironment, а на window (https://learn.javascript.ru/scope-new-function)